# CMake generator expressions with $<CONFIG> evaluates differently on Windows and Linux

Tags: cmake

I have the following simple example in CMake:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Hello! $<CONFIG>")
```

When I run:

```
 cmake --build . --config Debug --target MyTarget --verbose
```

I get in the output on Windows:

```
 "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo "Hello! Debug"
```

and on Linux:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E echo Hello!\
```

It seems that on Linux `$<CONFIG>` is evaluated to the empty string. I want to mention that that on Windows I use `cmake version 3.24.1` and on Linux I use `cmake version 3.22.1`

Is this a bug in CMake or am I using `$<CONFIG>` in a wrong way?
Is it possible to get the configuration in any other way?

My actual use case is that I need to copy the build output in different directories based on configuration and I'm using `set(installDirectory "${artifactsDirectory}/$<LOWER_CASE:$<CONFIG>>")` which works as expected on Windows, but fails on Linux.

EDIT:
I've tried the example from [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#debugging) with similar results:

````
add_custom_command(TARGET ${name} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG_MODE>")```
````

On Windows (cmake version 3.24.1) it evaluates to:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo DEBUG_MODE
```

On Linux (cmake version 3.22.1) it evaluates to:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E echo
```

Comment: 1) Please show the exact configure commands you're using on Windows and Linux each. If you're not specifying the generator (-G) argument explicitly in your configure commands, also show which generator is the default for you (you can find it in the output of `cmake --help`). 2) Please also say what version of CMake you have installed _on each machine_. 3) When I configure on Ubuntu with CMake 3.26 and `cmake -S . -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and then run build (`cmake --build build/`), the generator expression evaluates in to `Debug`.

Comment: @user OP is not using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` but `--config` option.

Comment: @KamilCuk all the more reason what they wrote should be working. I just tried with `Ninja Multi-Config` generator, and that also evaluates the generator expression on CMake 3.26.

Comment: Related: [feature-request: when CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is unset for single-config, expand $<CONFIG> to the toolchain-specific default build type](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24883)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a bug in CMake

No.

> am I using $ in a wrong way?

Correct way.

> Is it possible to get the configuration in any other way?

The configuration is empty on Linux, so you are getting correct result.

---

From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

```
--config

**For multi-configuration generators**, choose configuration <cfg>.`.
```

Because you are not using multi-configuration generator on Linux, the option is just ignored. Use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` for single-configuration generator like Make on Linux or use a multi-configuration generator on Linux (Ninja multi-config). See also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html .

Comment: wait hold on... who said they're doing single-config? And I just tried with single config and the generator expression evaluated just fine. What CMake version are you running?

Comment: The default on Linux is Make, which is single, default on windows is visual studio, which is multi. I did not test it. If you generate config in single config, `--config` is just ignored, the generated Makefile is static, it can't be modified.

Comment: I just tested with `Unix Makefiles` and `Ninja` and both will evaluate the generator expression on CMake 3.26. This statement seems wrong: "_The configuration is empty on Linux, so you are getting correct result._"

Comment: I fail to understand. The OPs CMake configuration of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE on Linux is empty, because `$<CONFIG>` evaluates to nothing. `all the more reason what they wrote should be working` In case you are using single-config generator without specifying `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, then `$<CONFIG>` is empty, which (I guessed correctly considered accepted) is presented by OPs Linux case. Try to create an empty cmake project, configure with `cmake ..` with Make and build with `cmake --build . --config anything` and see if `$<CONFIG>` changes to `--config` argument.

Comment: "_In case you are using single-config generator without specifying CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE, then $<CONFIG> is empty_" - that's what I was missing. I was trying with it set via `-D`.